# Find the separatrix of a dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hamilton-equations

I have the following system with kinetic energy: $T = \frac{m\dot{x}^2}{2}$ and potential energy: $V=ax-x^3$. I want to find if there are any separatrices and if there are, is there a condition on $a$.

THIS IS WHAT I HAVE DONE:

Hamilton's Equations give: $\begin{cases}\dot{q} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p}=\frac{p}{m} \\ \dot{p} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial q} = a-3q^2 \end{cases}$

The fixed points are: $\left(-\sqrt{\frac{a}{3}}, 0\right)$ and $\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{3}}, 0\right)$.

Taking the double derivative wrt $q$ of the potential we have:$V'' = -6q$, therefore only $\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{3}}, 0\right)$ corresponds to a saddle point. From my understanding, the separatrices are meeting at the sadde point but I don't know how to find them.

Here is the contour plot for the hamiltonian:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at the level curves of $H$.

Comment: @HansLundmark I have tried that and did not find anything conclusive.

Comment: Well, what *did* you find then? Did you try plotting the level curves on the computer? Did you try drawing the phase portrait on the computer (you can use "streamplot" on Wolfram Alpha, for example)?

Comment: @HansLundmark I added the contour plot !

Comment: OK, fine! Now make sure that your contour plot also includes the particular level curve that passes through the saddle point. (By the way, you're missing a minus sign in your equation for $\dot p$; it's supposed to be $\dot p = - \partial H/\partial q$.)

Comment: @HansLundmark noted for the mistake, I used Streamplot this time, it looks "different" than what I had before from another website, but we can see the saddle point more. Isn't there an analytical way to determine the existence of the separatrices with the mathematics I showed?

Comment: That plot doesn't look right. After all, the solution curves look nothing like the level curves that you had before! It should look something like [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=streamplot+%7By%2C-1%2Bx%5E2%7D%2Cx%3D-3..3%2Cy%3D-3..3).